# A series from textbook

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does it make sense to try to compute it exactly since there is nothing that would suggest this is possible?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{\log(n+1)}{n}$$

Comment: Are you supposed to compute it? Or prove convergence/divergence?

Comment: I'm supposed to compute it exactly.

Comment: Compute the first ten terms? Compute the 100th term? Compute the first 100 terms??? Compute what?

Comment: Express it using known constants.

Comment: It converges by the Alternating Series Test, but I have no clue how to proceed from there. Try the Estimation Theorem?

Comment: $\eta'(1)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\log(n)}n ~=~ \gamma\ln2-\frac{\ln^22}2$